# Number of ways you can visit places

Tags: combinatorics

A country has n cities, each of which is connected by road to every other city. A tourist wants to tour the country in such a way that starting from city $1$, she visits each city exactly once, and returns to city $1$. In how many ways can she do this? 
My approach.
Since going from city 1 to any other city we have the choice of $(n-1)$ cities thus we can choose any manner of visit
So my answer is $(n-1)! $
Is this correct.?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. This number is actually number of Hamiltonian cycles in a complete graph on $n$ vertices.

Comment: I don't know what is a hamiltonian cylcle

Comment: It is a cycle that visits every vertex of the graph exactly once.

Comment: Ohh.i didn't know this.